# The equivalent of splice for an object with numeric keys

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object like this:

```
const obj = {
        0: { name:'zero'},
        1: { name: 'one'}, 
        3: { name: 'three'},
        4: { name: 'four'}
    };
```

and I'd like to "pack" it, so that if the keys were array indexes, there'd be no gaps in the array.

```
{
    0: { name:'zero', ...},
    1: { name: 'one', ...}, 
    2: { name: 'three', ...},
    3: { name: 'four', ...}
}
```

I don't want to replace the `obj`, I want to do it destructively.

The way I figure it, I have two jobs: 1) find the gap where the key is missing (eventually, I'd like to do this for any number of gaps), 2) fill in the gap by moving values backwards.

In the loop where I search for the missing key, it seems like the `break` happens right away.  Also, the remaining code (which I think might work) is very verbose.  Can anyone help me find a better solution?

```js
const obj = {
        0: { name:'zero'},
        1: { name: 'one'}, 
        3: { name: 'three'},
        4: { name: 'four'}
    };
    
let expectedKey = 0
for (const [key, value] in obj) {
    if (key !== expectedKey) break
    expectedKey++
}

let missingKey = expectedKey
let keys = Object.keys(obj)
console.log(`missing key is ${missingKey} <<< why is this wrong`)

for (let k = missingKey; k < keys.length; k++) {
    let nextKey = (k == keys.length-1) ? null : k+1
    if (nextKey) obj[k] = obj[nextKey]
}

lastKey = keys[keys.length-1]
delete obj[lastKey]

console.log(obj[3])
```

Comment: Just don't use an object with numeric keys, use a proper array?

Comment: Your problem is that `key` is a string (it's a property name, not an index!) so `!== 0` will never be true.

Comment: What does it mean “I don't want to replace the obj, I want to do it destructively.”, exactly. Use another words.

Comment: @Ucho He wants to mutate (modify) the existing object, not create a new object and overwrite the variable

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - your clarifications helped me get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the values to an object.

```js
var obj = { 0: { name:'zero'}, 1: { name: 'one'},  3: { name: 'three'}, 4: { name: 'four'} };

obj = Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj));

console.log(obj);
```

O you could reassign the values to a new key, if necessary.

```js
var obj = { 0: { name:'zero'}, 1: { name: 'one'},  3: { name: 'three'}, 4: { name: 'four'} },
    i = 0,
    k;

for (k in obj) {
    if (+k !== i) {
        obj[i] = obj[k];
        delete obj[k];
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Using a queue for the leftover keys. This works for more than one leftover key.

```js
var obj = { 0: { name:'zero'}, 1: { name: 'one'},  3: { name: 'three'}, 4: { name: 'four'} },
    i = 0,
    k,
    queue = [];

for (k in obj) {
    if (+k !== i) {
        obj[i] = obj[k];
        queue.push(+k);
    }
    if (queue[0] === i) queue.shift();
    i++;
}
while(queue.length) delete obj[queue.shift()];

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: "*I want to do it destructively.*"

Comment: Thanks Nina Scholz, I'll use this.  Do you see any reason why I shouldn't move `delete obj[k];` to after the loop? Won't the next iteration just overwrite the key I'd be deleting?

Comment: do you have only one missing index?

Comment: Ah.  Yes, at the moment, but I might need to generalize.  I guess then, I'd test for inclusion in a set, and then delete the last N (set length) after the loop?

Comment: you could take a queue and adjust the keys insiode for later deleting. please see edit.

Comment: wow, i would have done that so much less elegantly.  thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can spread [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) within a `{}` to get consecutive keys:

```js
const obj = {
        0: { name:'zero'},
        1: { name: 'one'}, 
        3: { name: 'three'},
        4: { name: 'four'}
    };
    
const newObj = { ...Object.values(obj) }

console.log(newObj)
```

`Object.values()` returns an array of `values`. When you spread it within a `{}`, the indexes become `keys`

Comment: "*I want to do it destructively.*"